# jQuery Validation - Hide Error Message

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin and want to disable the  or element/container it creates to display the error 'message'.

Basically, I want the input element with the error to have the error class but NOT create an additional element containing the error message.

Is this possible?

I have just thought of a CSS workaround, but it doesn't really fix the fact that the element is still being created?

```
<style>
label.simpleValidationError {display: none !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: jQuery just by itself does not display or create any kind of error messages, you will have to go a little bit more into detail what you are doing and what you are using to accomplish that

Comment: Sorry, i'm using the jQuery Validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: ~ That's still not really a LOT of extra information, altho it does clarify some things. What are you doing when you create the validator (options wise) and how are you processing the data it gives you?

Comment: "I have just thought of a CSS workaround, but it doesn't really fix the fact that the element is still being created" I don't understand what's wrong with it -- although the element is created, it's hidden as you wish. Right?

Answer (score 71):

Use the Validator errorPlacement option with an empty function:

```
$("selector").validate({ errorPlacement: function(error, element) {} });
```

This effectively places the error messages nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this code:

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

$("selector").validate();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could set the [showErrors](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option to a function that only performs element highlighting:

```
$("selector").validate({
    showErrors: function() {
        if (this.settings.highlight) {
            for (var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; ++i) {
                this.settings.highlight.call(this, this.errorList[i].element,
                    this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
            }
        }
        if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
            for (var i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; ++i) {
                this.settings.unhighlight.call(this, elements[i],
                    this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That relies heavily on the validation plugin's internals, though, so it's probably not safe. The best would be for the plugin to expose a `defaultHighlightElements()` method the same way it does for `defaultShowErrors()`, but it's not the case (yet).

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to hide the error messages and to turn my `input` fields and `textarea` red, on error.
Here's a small example :

http://jsfiddle.net/MFRYm/51/

and fully working code in case jsfiddle breaks ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> Demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>    

      <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    .error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#email_form" ).validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      }, highlight: function(input) {
            $(input).addClass('error');
        },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){}
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="form" id="email_form" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="item" style="clear:left;">
        <label>E Mail *</label>
        <input id="femail" name="email" type="text">
    </div>
    Type invalid email and press Tab key
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue. I didn't want error messages, just the highlights of the form inputs that needed attention.
The messages were already empty like `<?php $msj='""';?>` but still created the error elements/containers after the labels..

So to quickly stop this from happening I edited the jquery.validate.js file by commenting out the only line which states `label.insertAfter(element);` around line 697 +/-..

It's just a noob's workaround ;) but it did it!

Answer (score 2):

As I am using CSS to style the label.valid, label.error in jquery validate, this button cleared all the errors and left and data in the form fields in tact.

```
     <button  onclick="$('label.error').css('display', 'none');return false;">Clear Error </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution with only CSS:

```
label.valid {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a far simpler and semantically preferable solution would be to use css

```
label.error {
  position:absolute;
  left:20000px;
  top:0;
  }
input.error {
  border:red 1px;
 }
```

No JS required, easier to manage and someone with a screen reader will actually have some indication that they have missed something

Comment: Good point on screen readers, I should take that into account more often!

Answer (score 1):

I had a project that developed by another validation library, I wanted to add validate library to use its features for check the form is valid or not (used validation library doesn't have that feature)

**My soloution was :**
I just added validate library by its CDN

and use validate feature on click :

```
$(document).on('click','#buttonID',function(){
   var form = $( "#formID" );
   form.validate();
   console.log(form.valid());
});
```

and tried to hide error messages that raised by jquery validate by adding CSS code:

```
label.error{
   display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onfocus and an onkeyup that would remove the error message.

```
$("selector").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false
});
```